# Twitter on SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007

I have been tasked with adding a twitter feed to a SharePoint 2007 site.

I have attempted to use the widget code that twitter generates for users and I have only been able to get the text "Tweets by @USER" to display linking to the twitter page.

I have tried to use the XML and Content editor web parts without luck.

Is there anyway to do this now that twitter does not use RSS feeds?

Comment: Have you tried the twitter widget? https://sharepointdon.wordpress.com/2009/10/17/add-twitter-widget-to-sharepoint-2007/

Comment: @jpollar Yes. I did exactly that but instead of displaying the feed it just displays the text link.